# Two way SSL with NSURLConnection on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to have a UIWebView accessing an https website requesting a client certificate for two way SSL. 
My starting point has been Apple documentation: [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160809064539/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13)
There is also plenty of help on stackoverflow.

I came up with the following code to answer the authentication challenge, loading the p12 identity file and the crt intermediates certs, and then presenting them.

```c
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSLog(@"Auth method: %@", challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod);
if([challenge previousFailureCount] <5) {
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [challenge protectionSpace];
    NSString *authMethod = [protectionSpace authenticationMethod];
    if(authMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust ) {
        NSLog(@"Verifying The Trust");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:[protectionSpace serverTrust]] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else if(authMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate ) {
        NSLog(@"Getting client certificate");
        SecIdentityRef identity = [self getClientCertificate:@"mycert" withPassword:@"password"];
        SecCertificateRef intermediateCert = [self getCertificate:@"intermediatecert"];
        SecCertificateRef rootCA = [self getCertificate:@"cacert"];

        NSMutableArray *combinedCerts = [NSMutableArray array];
        [combinedCerts addObject:(__bridge id)intermediateCert];
        [combinedCerts addObject:(__bridge id)rootCA];

        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity certificates:combinedCerts persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

        NSLog(@"Sending credential");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not dealing with challenge %@",authMethod);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Auth Challenge Failed");
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
}
```

The results are, well... not really good. The call is finishing with an handshake failure. Calling the website with chrome and the same cert is actually working fine, which led me to check in Wireshark what is the difference between the two calls.

With Chrome, everything looks fine, the way it should for a TLS handshake.

iOS is going with TLSv1 and Chrome with SSLv3: this shouldn't be a problem.
What is more intriguing is my program sending for some reason and empty certificate handshake msg:

```
Frame 102: 66 bytes on wire (528 bits), 66 bytes captured (528 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_XX:XX:XX (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX), Dst: Cisco-Li_3d:96:d0 (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: imac.local (192.168.1.9), Dst: xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63324 (63324), Dst Port: https (443), Seq: 187, Ack: 4244, Len: 12
Secure Sockets Layer
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 7
    Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
        Length: 3
        Certificates Length: 0
```

and then a second one with the proper content:

```
Frame 108: 248 bytes on wire (1984 bits), 248 bytes captured (1984 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_XX:XX:XX (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX), Dst: Cisco-Li_XX:XX:XX (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: imac.local (192.168.1.9), Dst: xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 63325 (63325), Dst Port: https (443), Seq: 2947, Ack: 4244, Len: 194
[3 Reassembled TCP Segments (2954 bytes): #106(1380), #107(1380), #108(194)]
Secure Sockets Layer
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Certificate
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 2949
    Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
        Length: 2945
        Certificates Length: 2942
        Certificates (2942 bytes)
            Certificate Length: 1024
            Certificate (id-at-organizationName=XX,id-at-organizationalUnitName=XX,id-at-serialNumber=XX,id-at-countryName=XX,id-at-commonName=XXXXXX)
            Certificate Length: 995
            Certificate (id-at-serialNumber=XX,id-at-commonName=XXXX,id-at-countryName=XX)
            Certificate Length: 914
            Certificate (id-at-commonName=XXXX,id-at-countryName=XX)
```

Did anybody ever see something like that?

I'm pretty sure I made some really stupid mistake somewhere as it seems some other people with pretty much the same code are managing to achieve what I've been trying to do for some days now...

Comment: did you find out anything about it? It could be helpful to know. Could you share your findings?

Comment: @CyranoB old post. but have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @janusfidel This is getting really old... I eventually reimplemented everything using OpenSSL.